# Fedora Configuration to enable TLS 1.2

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, openssl, fedora

I want to enable TLS 1.2 on the linux server to access third party ERP system. Please guide me through the steps and commands that I have to follow.

```
My Apache version: Apache/2.2.9 (Unix)
My OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 0.9.8b 04 May 2006
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow provides answers to specific programming and development questions. Unfortunately, this question does not appear to be related to programming, and its not a specific question (other than "where's the tutorial to do X").

Comment: What version of Fedora is this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless Fedora provides backports for TLS 1.2, the versions you mention are too old:

- OpenSSL: Supported since version
  [1.0.1](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x21)
- Apache httpd: Introduced in
  [2.2.23](https://www.apachelounge.com/Changelog.html)

Anyway you can check if it actually is supported. Restrict the [allowed protocols](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol) to TLS 1.2 *only* and try connecting with a recent browser. Edit your httpd.conf to:

```
SSLProtocol TLSv1.2
```

Comment: I Have tried `SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2` in the httpd.conf. Unfortunately its giving an error when I start apache. `module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping`.

Comment: This is just a warning. It appears if you have a duplicate `LoadModule` directive in your httpd.conf. Apache should be running nevertheless, as the message implies. Check for error messages like `SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.2'`.